# How to find pixel height of a div with a consistent result between FF and Chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, html, height

Back story: I have an SVG canvas with some polylines on it.  I also have some HTML `<span>` and `<textarea>` elements that need to be positioned precisely in relation to those polylines.

I started by putting the HTML elements in the SVG in `<foreignElement>` tags, but I had a problem there because IE doesn't see them at all and Firefox doesn't see the `<textarea>`s.  So I took them out of the SVG and now every browser sees them.

So far so good.  Now the only way I know to make sure they position correctly with the polylines is to give both the HTML elements and the SVG canvas absolute positions with CSS.

Here's my problem.  Above all these elements is a header div.  I want the whole SVG business to sit at a reasonable distance below the header.  Say 15px.  But since the SVG is absolutely positioned, I need to know the height of that header div to get the SVG and related HTML elements into the right place.

I've tried jQuery's `.height()` method and some related methods.  The problem with all of them is that Firefox and Chrome give two different results.  I know this doesn't reflect a real pixel height difference between the two, because I can see visually that the header is slightly taller in FF, yet FF gives a smaller height reading.

How can I get a browser-consistent height reading for my header div?  Or at least one that I can use to absolutely position other elements at the same distance below it in every browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with this function

```
function getHeight() {
    return Math.min(
            Math.min(document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight),
            Math.min(document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight),
            Math.min(document.body.clientHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight)
        );

}
```

or simply with `document.documentElement.clientHeight`, which usually does the trick for me in all the browsers I use for testing (Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera)

[edit] The function above returns the width and height of the body, in order to use it for any div, use this one

```
function getHeight(div) {
        return Math.min(div.scrollHeight, div.offsetHeight, div.clientHeight);  
    }
```

You can use it like this

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDivId');
console.log('the height is ' + getHeight(myDiv));
```

[edit2]Keep in mind that the divs might actually have a different size depending on the browser.

Let's say this is google chrome and the green bar at top is the navigation bar, with a height of 75px. You have it at 100%, filling up your screen, who has 1000px height, and you place an 100 pixels div to the top and also stick an 100px div to the bottom of the screen (with blue). The purple div between them will have an 725px height.

[image: google chrome example]

And this below is firefox. It's placed on the same 1000px screen, also at 100%, but its navigation bar has 100px height. With the same 100px blue divs to the top and the bottom, the purple div will have a height of 700px here, different from chrome.

[image: firefox example]

Of course, this is a very, very simple example and I doubt this is your case. But you might have a similar problem with div placements and it's something you should try to check.

Comment: Sorry if I'm misunderstanding, but it looks to me like this will only give me the height of the entire document.  Is that right?  I need to get the height of a particular div element.

Comment: Ah, sorry, you are right. I use this function for the document, but you can easily modify it to use it with any div. I'll edit my post and add the new function

Comment: Thanks for replying.  I'm still getting different readings in FF vs. Chrome for a couple of my divs.  Do you know of any other height properties I could add into that list of parameters, or how the three you listed get calculated in the first place?

Comment: Well, this might have something to do with your divs and not the methods. Can't you post a jsfiddle? The thing is Firefox and Chrome don't have the same window height, for example, so if you have certain arangements of div, with a height calculated in percentages, based on the total height of the window, the divs WILL have different heights on each browsers. I added an example to my post

Comment: I'm still working out the details of how I went wrong in the first place, but I removed the fixed heights from my divs and tried out your function and it worked!  You were right - despite FF rendering the div with a visually greater height and producing a lower height reading, it was really giving an accurate pixel height for its own rendering.  Maybe FF and Chrome don't have the same ratio of browser "pixel" to screen pixel?  Anyway, thanks very much for your detailed help.